# Script criando várias divs

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Estou usando javascript para atualizar uma `div` a cada 5 segundos, e a cada 5 segundos a `div` atualiza, mas está criando várias `div` iguais.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
session_start();
$url ="http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$_SESSION['URL'] = $url;

echo("    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#chatDiv').load('$url');

  var refreshId = setInterval(function(){
      $('#chatDiv').load('$url');}, 5000);
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false});
  });
</script>");
```

Comment: O que retorna da URL que vc está carregando pra dentro da div `#chatDiv`?

Comment: Estou recebendo a url atual da pagina

Comment: Só lembrando que este `HTTP_HOST` é vulnerável, qualquer um pode alterar ele, uma vez que parte do header enviado pelo cliente. Isso é, mudando isso você irá fazer uma requisição para outro site...

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro usar o `$.get`, e com isso pode filtrar o que retorna e pegar apenas o conteúdo da `div`:

```
session_start();
$url ="http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$_SESSION['URL'] = $url;

echo("    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.get( '$url', function(data){
      $('#chatDiv').html( $(data).filter('#chatDiv').html() );
   });

  var refreshId = setInterval(function(){
      $.get( '$url', function(data){ $('#chatDiv').html( $(data).filter('#chatDiv').html() ); })}, 5000);
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false});
  });
</script>");
```